# Issue running embedded jetty on SSL

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to run SSL with embedded jetty latest version(9.4.x).Followed following steps:

1. created a jetty.xml with following contents:

   ```
       <Get name="ThreadPool">
         <Set name="minThreads" type="int"><Property name="jetty.threadPool.minThreads" deprecated="threads.min" default="10"/></Set>
         <Set name="maxThreads" type="int"><Property name="jetty.threadPool.maxThreads" deprecated="threads.max" default="200"/></Set>
         <Set name="idleTimeout" type="int"><Property name="jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout" deprecated="threads.timeout" default="60000"/></Set>
         <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
       </Get>

       <!-- =========================================================== -->
       <!-- Add shared Scheduler instance                               -->
       <!-- =========================================================== -->
       <Call name="addBean">
         <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ScheduledExecutorScheduler"/>
         </Arg>
       </Call>


       <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
         <Set name="secureScheme"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.secureScheme" default="https" /></Set>
         <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.securePort" deprecated="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" />8447</Set>
         <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputBufferSize" deprecated="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
         <Set name="outputAggregationSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.outputAggregationSize" deprecated="jetty.output.aggregation.size" default="8192" /></Set>
         <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.requestHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
         <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.responseHeaderSize" deprecated="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
         <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendServerVersion" deprecated="jetty.send.server.version" default="true" /></Set>
         <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.sendDateHeader" deprecated="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
         <Set name="headerCacheSize"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.headerCacheSize" default="512" /></Set>
         <Set name="delayDispatchUntilContent"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.delayDispatchUntilContent" deprecated="jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent" default="true"/></Set>
         <Set name="maxErrorDispatches"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.maxErrorDispatches" default="10"/></Set>
         <Set name="blockingTimeout"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.blockingTimeout" default="-1"/></Set>
         <Set name="persistentConnectionsEnabled"><Property name="jetty.httpConfig.persistentConnectionsEnabled" default="true"/></Set>
       </New>


       <Set name="handler">
         <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
           <Set name="handlers">
            <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
              <Item>
                <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
              </Item>
              <Item>
                <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
              </Item>
            </Array>
           </Set>
         </New>
       </Set>

       <!-- =========================================================== -->
       <!-- extra server options                                        -->
       <!-- =========================================================== -->
       <Set name="stopAtShutdown"><Property name="jetty.server.stopAtShutdown" default="true"/></Set>
       <Set name="stopTimeout"><Property name="jetty.server.stopTimeout" default="5000"/></Set>
       <Set name="dumpAfterStart"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpAfterStart" deprecated="jetty.dump.start" default="false"/></Set>
       <Set name="dumpBeforeStop"><Property name="jetty.server.dumpBeforeStop" deprecated="jetty.dump.stop" default="false"/></Set>

     <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
       <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
       <Call name="addCustomizer">
         <Arg>
           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer">
             <Arg name="sniHostCheck" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck" default="true"/></Arg>
             <Arg name="stsMaxAgeSeconds" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsMaxAgeSeconds" default="-1"/></Arg>
             <Arg name="stsIncludeSubdomains" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsIncludeSubdomains" default="false"/></Arg>
           </New>
         </Arg>
       </Call>
     </New>
   <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
       <Set name="KeyStorePath">trust.jks</Set>
       <Set name="KeyStorePassword">testpwd</Set>
       <Set name="KeyManagerPassword">testpwd</Set>
       <Set name="TrustStorePath">trust.jks</Set>
       <Set name="TrustStorePassword">testpwd</Set>
       <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"/>
       <Set name="keyStoreType">JKS</Set>
       <Set name="keyStoreProvider">SUN</Set>
       <Set name="trustStoreType">JKS</Set>
   <!--    <Set name="protocol">TLS</Set>-->
       <Set name="renegotiationAllowed">true</Set>
       <Set name="includeProtocols">
           <Array type="java.lang.String">
               <Item>SSLv2Hello</Item>
               <Item>SSLv3</Item>
               <Item>TLSv1</Item>
               <Item>TLSv1.1</Item>
               <Item>TLSv1.2</Item>
             </Array>
       </Set>
            <Set name="IncludeCipherSuites">
             <Array type="java.lang.String">
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV</item>
               <item>TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA</item>
               <item>SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5</item>
               <item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5</item>
               <item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5</item>
               <item>TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA</item>
               <item>TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5</item>
             </Array>
           </Set>
   </New>

     <Call name="addConnector">
       <Arg>
         <New id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
           <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
           <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptors" deprecated="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
           <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.selectors" deprecated="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
           <Arg name="factories">
             <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
              <Item>
                           <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                               <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                               <Arg name="sslContextFactory">
                                   <Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/>
                               </Arg>
                           </New>
                       </Item>
             </Array>
           </Arg>

           <Set name="host">192.168.10.129</Set>
           <Set name="port">8080</Set>
           <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" deprecated="ssl.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
           <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.ssl.soLingerTime" deprecated="ssl.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
           <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" deprecated="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
           <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.ssl.acceptQueueSize" deprecated="ssl.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>

         </New>
       </Arg>
     </Call>
   </Configure>
   ```
2. created certificate with following commands:

   keytool -genkey -alias jetty -keyalg RSA -keysize 1024 -validity 365 -keypass testpwd -keystore identity.jks -storepass testpwd

   keytool -export -alias jetty -file root.cer  -keystore identity.jks -storepass testpwd

   keytool -import -alias jetty -file root.cer -keystore trust.jks -storepass testpwd
3. created jetty-runner jar using jetty-runner maven plugin
4. running jetty runner with following commad:
   java -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true -Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.debug=all:handshake:verbose -jar jetty-runner.jar --config jetty.xml my.war

Server is up as shown in the log file on the specified port and SSL, but when trying to open on browser or any http client is throwing handshake error.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake.
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly.

Comment: The logs you captured with `-Djavax.net.debug` will tell you what is going on.  Common causes: a Cipher list incompatibility. (your setup has a syntax error btw, its `<Item>` not `<item>`)

Answer (score 0):

```html
i changed <item> to <Item>. STill the issue persists Debug logs says:

2016-10-09 01:37:20.021:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@2ac519dc(je
tty,h=[],w=[]) for SslContextFactory@3d53e6f7(file:///D:/tmp/trust.jks,file:///D
:/tmp/trust.jks)
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=localhost, ST=localhost, C
=IN
  Issuer:  CN=localhost, OU=localhost, O=localhost, L=localhost, ST=localhost, C
=IN
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x73f282d8
  Valid from Sun Oct 09 01:12:51 IST 2016 until Mon Oct 09 01:12:51 IST 2017

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
2016-10-09 01:37:20.153:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnecto
r@54dc8eb9{SSL,[ssl]}{localhost:8444}
2016-10-09 01:37:20.155:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @16677ms
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```